# Xamarin Cannot perform this action after onSavedInstanceState

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, onbackpressed

I am opening a camera screen for my Zxing scanner and I also use custom template for that. In my custom template I have set up `SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` but when I click on it, I am getting this error `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

Here is my click event:

```
private void Toolbar_NavigationClick(object sender, Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar.NavigationClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainActivity = Activity as MainActivity;
        mainActivity?.OnBackPressed();
    }
```

The full stack trace of my error:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState 
--- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:775)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher.n_onClick(Native Method)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher.onClick(Toolbar_NavigationOnClickEventDispatcher.java:37)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22523)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The back button on the device is working perfectly but I don't know why I am getting this error on `onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 0):

did you override this method in your activity?

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                Finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```